# Does nodes have maximum limit of transactions

Tags: nodes, clients

Does geth/parity nodes have a maximum limit of transactions that they  can have (in queue) after which they stop accepting transactions (or apply back pressure or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Parity**

Has a default queue size of 8192, but this can be controlled using the `--tx-queue-size` command line option.

```
--tx-queue-size=[LIMIT]
    Maximum amount of transactions in the queue (waiting to
    be included in next block). (default: 8192)
```

The conditions for transactions to be dropped from the transaction pool/queue are described in the [Dropping Conditions](https://wiki.parity.io/Transactions-Queue#dropping-conditions) section of the [Transaction Queue wiki](https://wiki.parity.io/Transactions-Queue).

**Geth**

Default *global* queue size of 1024, which is again configurable, with `--txpool.globalqueue`. There are also options for per-account queue sizes.

```
  --txpool.globalqueue value   Maximum number of non-executable transaction slots for all accounts (default: 1024)
```

(See Transaction Pool Options of [this](https://geth.ethereum.org/interface/Command-Line-Options) page.)